# Linux command line doesnt take true as command argument

Tags: linux, bash

So I have this bash script example.sh which has a command that takes in an argument like this

```
./example.sh import -override true
```

It does not take in the parameter true. From what I googled true seems to be a command in linux. Is that what is causing a problem?
Is there a way to take in  true as parameter or do I need to find another argument?

Answer (score 5):

`true` is a command, but that isn't relevant here. The string "true' is only interpreted as a command when it appears in command position (roughly speaking, the first non-assignment word of the command). Here, it is just an argument to `./example.sh`. Without knowing the contents of `example.sh`, we can't say more about why the argument is not processed.